# How to feed data to a Openlayers page

Tags: openlayers-2, import

I have a webpage, on which I am running Openlayers to query a WMS server.

Now, I want to provide my own data to Openlayers. I do not want to use a WMS server. I have a php script, which will generate tiles in png format, and I want to display them in Openlayers. The reason for not going with WMS is that I have 6 or higher dimensional data, and I will make two dimensional projections thereof, and I want Openlayers to treat this as a map.

How do I feed data to openlayers? I asked this question in the IRC, and also looked on the Internet. I didn't find much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers supports data via something called [Layers](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html)

There are various types of Layers that OpenLayers Supports. Broadly speaking, Layers can be grouped into two major classes: Vectors and Image Based Layers. You have already created a php service to serve our PNG Images. Hence you need to use one of the Image based Layers.

I have no knowledge of your data, so I'm **assuming** that your data is spatial in nature. Your images (from the php script) will display the data at some particular location. Hence I'll suggest that you make your php service implement the [WMS Specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms). You need not implement all the specifications; You need to implement only those features which are used by OpenLayers' [WMS Class](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html).

To figure out which WMS operations are used by OpenLayers, I'll suggest that you play with one of the WMS [OpenLayers Samples](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/), and see which requests are being sent, by using FireBug or Fiddler.

For example, looking at the sample given at: [WMS Example](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/wms.html) 
I could see that the following GET parameters were passed:

```
BBOX    0,45,11.25,56.25
FORMAT  image/jpeg
HEIGHT  256
LAYERS  basic
REQUEST GetMap
SERVICE WMS
SRS EPSG:4326
STYLES  
VERSION 1.1.1
WIDTH   256
```

Out of these, your php script will work, if you implement only the following three paramters: `BBOX, HEIGHT & WIDTH`. You could set the rest of the properties in your OpenLayers Application

Comment: I agree with the above answer, you should also look into OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ if you do not want to follow WMS rather create your own.

Comment: @byom: The problem with XYZ layer, is that you need tiles in `http://example.com/tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png` url. Secondly, you will need to convert from (z,x,y) to a bounding box in the php script.  Both of these issues can be solved, but they require additional code. A WMS-like service will be much simpler.

Comment: Ofcourse, using WMS in client side will be much simpler. I suggested using OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ because the question says "I do not want to use a WMS server"

Comment: @all if i need layer in TLD/Z/x/y then i can, after modifying the openlayers.layer.xyz cl<ass, also actually extent this directly to TLD/Z/x/y/a/b/c/proj_axis_1/proj_axis_2 . so that is also a good idea ...